# how to edit timeout options inside website.conf file using apache2 on docker

Tags: linux, docker, apache

I am running a web app with `apache2` using `docker` & `docker-compose`,
but I am always getting a timeout error when I perform a long request. I want to edit the timeout options in the apache2 so that it takes more time,, I have tried to add `TimeOut 2400` to the `demo_site.conf` file but still not working.

here is what the project structure looks like :

```
-www
-docker-compose.yaml
-Dockerfile
-website.conf
```

***docker-compose.yaml***

```yaml
version: "2"

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always 
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/kml_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/kml_files
      - ./www/demo_app/temp_kml_file:/var/www/html/demo_app/temp_kml_file
      - ./www/demo_app/upload:/var/www/html/demo_app/upload
      - ./data/log:/var/log/apache2
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=qweqwe
      - POSTGRES_USER=qweqwe
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwewqe

  django-apache2:
    build: .
    container_name: water_maps
    restart: always 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=qwewqe
      - POSTGRES_USER=qwewqe
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwewqe
    ports:
      - 4000:80
      - 4001:443
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/kml_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/kml_files
      - ./www/demo_app/temp_kml_file:/var/www/html/demo_app/temp_kml_file
      - ./www/demo_app/upload:/var/www/html/demo_app/upload
      - ./data/log:/var/log/apache2

      # - ./data/config/etc/apache2:/etc/apache2
    # command: sh -c 'python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata the_db.json '
    command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&python manage.py compilemessages && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
    # command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata last.json && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'

    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

# Avoid tzdata infinite waiting bug
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Africa/Cairo

RUN apt clean
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN apt -y install certbot python3-certbot-apache
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt update
#Add sf to avoid ln: failed to create hard link '/usr/bin/pip': File exists
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install django ptvsd
RUN apt install wait-for-it
RUN apt-get -y install gettext
RUN apt-get -y install poppler-utils
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN service apache2 restart
COPY www/demo_app/water_maps/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./demo_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 80 5432
WORKDIR /var/www/html/demo_app
#CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
#CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "--no-input"]
```

**demo_site.conf**

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/demo_app

<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        # ServerName test3.watermaps-eg.com
        # ServerAlias test3.watermaps-eg.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/



       Alias /static /var/www/html/demo_app/static
       Alias /en/upload  /var/www/html/demo_app/upload
       Alias /ar/upload  /var/www/html/demo_app/upload
       Alias /upload  /var/www/html/demo_app/upload

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app/upload>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        TimeOut 2400
</VirtualHost>
```